# Spring StateMachine Configuration : Naming StateMachine when using @EnableStateMachineFactory

Tags: configuration, factory, spring-statemachine

I would like to include several `StateMachine` configurations for dynamic instantiation using the `StateMachineFactory`. But the `@EnableStateMachineFactory` annotation allows for naming the factory. How does one name each Config (i.e. that extends `EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter`)?

Otherwise, it would be useful to have an example of how to use the `setMachineID` method within the configuration definition, if that's possible.

Comment: If you have inline code please mark it with backticks (`\``). This helps make your question more readable.

Answer (score 5):

Having these `enable` annotations with Spring `@Configuration' classes simply define bean names which gets registered with application context. Easiest to explained with examples:

```
@EnableStateMachine
```

`StateMachine` as bean `stateMachine`.

```
@EnableStateMachine(name = "fooMachine")
```

`StateMachine` as bean `fooMachine`.

```
@EnableStateMachine(name = {StateMachineSystemConstants.DEFAULT_ID_STATEMACHINE, "fooMachine"})
```

`StateMachine` as bean `stateMachine` with bean alias `fooMachine`.

```
@EnableStateMachineFactory
```

`StateMachineFactory` as bean `stateMachineFactory`.

```
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = "fooMachineFactory")
```

`StateMachineFactory` as bean `fooMachineFactory`.

```
@EnableStateMachineFactory(name = {StateMachineSystemConstants.DEFAULT_ID_STATEMACHINEFACTORY, "fooMachineFactory"})
```

`StateMachineFactory` as bean `stateMachineFactory` with bean alias `fooMachineFactory`.

Other than that the name of a `@Configuration` class(that extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter) doesn't matter. Thought in Spring a `@Configuration` class is also created as a bean meaning a below class will exist in Spring Application Context as bean `myConfig.MachineFactoryConfig`. Just one thing to remember in Spring as badly named class may result bean override!

```
public class MyConfig {
  @Configuration
  @EnableStateMachineFactory
  public static class MachineFactoryConfig extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<String, String> {
  }
}
```

What comes for `machineId` I just added a new section to docs [State Machine ID](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-machineid). (Only in snapshot build until we get next release out)